# Creating a connection with remote database using Cocoa

Tags: database, ms-access

How can I access a MS Access database from a remote server, which is on Windows platform,
using Cocoa and objective-C on Mac OS X? The server is located in remote location and it can only be accessed over internet.

How can I make connection with server over internet?
what all procedures to be used for making such applications?
If I need to use ODBC, what all are the steps required to achieve a connection?
I didn't find out any helpful documentations regarding these topics?
Is there any frameworks to be used?

Thanks in advance

mahaboob

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it's a MS Access file, you will need to setup a File Server on the remote machine. I guess you have already done that.

Now, since you have already ODBC installed on your Mac (I am assuming you have Mac OS X 10.2 or higher) you need a driver to open the MS Access file. You can find (buy, really) one [here](http://www.actualtechnologies.com/product_access.php). Check this [FAQ](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/mac-faq.html) out also. It has some interesting stuff about ODBC on Mac OS.

Now you are ready to code. You can use [ODBC API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714562(VS.85).aspx) directly in Objective-C (after all, it's **C**!) or you can try some pure Objective-C wrappers like [this one](http://download.cnet.com/ODBC-Cocoa-Class-Samples/3000-2247_4-64455.html). I would definitely recommend to stick with the native ODBC API to avoid headaches related to bugs on Open Source or Freeware, unsupported wrappers you might find on the Internet.